# How to draw this with tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want to learn how to draw things like this. Can you show me how to do this please?

so far i have already measured the rectangle:
,tikz \draw (0,0) -- (5.2,0) -- (5.2,2.6) -- (0,2.6) -- (0,0);

Comment: Note that K is located on a circle connecting B and D (center at `($(B)!0.5!(D)$)` using calc tikzlibrary).

Comment: I have measured the rectangle so far. Now i have following tikz:
,tikz \draw (0,0) -- (5.2,0) -- (5.2,2.6) -- (0,2.6) -- (0,0);

How can i connect it with k?

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code you have so far. Make sure that you provide a compilable [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) and point to the problem you have.

Comment: Another \draw or simply separate the new lines with a blank.  Also note `\draw (0,0) rectangle (5.2,2.6):`  Measureing the points is certainly easier to trying to construct K.

Comment: How can I add A B C D to the rectangle?

Comment: And thanks thats an easier method to draw a rectangle!

Comment: `\node[below left] (0,0) {A};` etc.  Why don't you just read the manual?

Comment: I believe asking Experts is more efficient that reading the manual. I did read the manual. But where does it show how to place the A a bit more nearer to the Rectangle?
Can you pls show me how to position the A nearer and more far away?

Comment: How can I add the B?

Comment: ,tikz \draw (0,0) rectangle (5.2,2.6); \node[below left] (0,0) {A}; \node[below right] (5.2,0) {B};  Doesn't really work for B

Comment: How do you make the grey box?

Comment: WIth "the manual" you mean this here? https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/LaTeX_Graphics_using_TikZ%3A_A_Tutorial_for_Beginners_(Part_1)—Basic_Drawing

Comment: Why don't you just help me?

Comment: @user279680  2D or 3D?

Comment: The manual can be opened by doing `texdoc pgfmanual` on your command line. Or you use the one that [CTAN](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) provides. Or the unofficial [tikz.dev](https://tikz.dev).

Comment: Why not show me both? :upside_down_smile:

Comment: Thanks this "the manual" has 1250 pages more than the other. I will try to learn

Comment: BTW, on futher thought, the `$15^\circ$` angle does not uniquely place K.  A and C also lie on the circle with B,D and K, so AK and DK are chords.  This makes `$AD=2r\sin 15^circ$` where $r$ is the radius.

Answer (score 5):

From your picture, I use 3dtools to draw. I guess the line `DA` is perpendicular to the plane `ABC` And then, the triangle `AKB` is right at `K`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,3dtools,angles,quotes}% https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[3d/install view={phi=60,theta=70,psi=0},declare function={r=3;},c/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}] 
    \path
    (0,0,0) coordinate  (A)
    (0,2*r,0) coordinate  (B)
    ({r*cos(30)},{r*sin(30)},0) coordinate  (K);
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myd}{sqrt(TD("(K)-(A)o(K)-(A)"))} ;
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myh}{\myd*tan(15)} ;
    \path
    (0,0,\myh) coordinate  (D)
    (0,2*r,\myh) coordinate  (C);
\path foreach \p/\g in {A/180,B/-90,K/-90,D/90,C/90}
{(\p)node[c]{}+(\g:2.5mm) node{$\p$}};  
\draw[3d/visible] (D) -- (A) -- (K) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) (D) -- (K);    
\draw[3d/hidden] (A) --(B) (A) --(C) ;
 \path pic[red]{3d circle through 3 points={%
        A={(D)},B={(K)},C={(B)}}};
    \end{tikzpicture}   
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looks great,

Comment: But when I copy and paste this in discord I get an compile Error.

Comment: Discord, as many other apps for organization, do not support LaTeX. At most they can manage MathJax, which do not support tikz. If you want something that can be rendered in discord, it should be on your question and I believe it will be off topic in this site

Comment: @user279680 You go to https://github.com/marmotghost/tikz-3dtools/blob/master/tikzlibrary3dtools.code.tex download that file and save the same folder of the file.

Answer (score 0):

This assumes planar geometry (not 3D).  (K) can be located anywhere on the red circle.  The angle really is $15^\circ$.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\R{3cm}%
  \draw[red] (0,0) circle [radius=\R];% illustration purposes only
  \coordinate (A) at (195: \R);% polar coordinates
  \coordinate (B) at (-15: \R);
  \coordinate (C) at (15: \R);
  \coordinate (D) at (165: \R);
  \coordinate (K) at (250: \R);% angle not important
  \path (A) node[below left] {A}
        (B) node[below right] {B}
        (C) node[above right] {C}
        (D) node[above left] {D}
        (K) node[below] {K};
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- cycle;
  \draw (A) -- (K) -- (B) (D) -- (K);
  \draw pic[draw, angle radius=1cm,
            angle eccentricity=1.3, 
            pic text=$15^\circ$,
            pic text options={font=\small, rotate=-60}]
          {angle = D--K--A}
        pic[draw, angle radius=3mm] {right angle = B--K--D};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]